# Updating App which was removed from sale

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, iphone-5

I have a confusion about my Application which is removed from sale by my self by Deselecting All countries from Rights & Pricing section. The reason why i have to do this is because i want to launch it into App store with new Update.

My Question is in this scenario will Apple Approve this Update version of the Application.

If No then is there any alternate solution for it please guide me friends.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apple should still approve the new update and then you can re-release it to the appstore. If this scenario didn't work for some reason an alternative would be to just change the availability date (under pricing) to some date crazy far in the future like 2014 and then change it back to a date in the past after your update is approved. God bless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing App by Deselecting All countries will just hide the Application from the store its still there ready for sale so while Update this App Apple will treat it similar like a normal App Update & will Approve it if all the things are correct.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 4):

1. When you remove app from sale Apple just hide your app from App Store.
2. Your app is not removed from App Store.
3. You can go ahead and release the update of your application.
4. Wait for Apple to approve it.
5. And release it on App Store.